# Segmentation fault detected in apache error log

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, php7, ubuntu-18.04

I have this problem on my Ubuntu Server:

**Problem**

Some time my sites are not reachable from the browser and I can see a "Time Out Error", however the server replies to PING requests. I checked the error.log file ~ 50MB of data similar to the following (in some hours of downtime).

In order to fix this error I have to reboot apache with the command *service apache2 restart*

```
[...]
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
[Sat Mar 09 14:33:05.391789 2019] [core:notice] [pid 5157] AH00051: child pid 9724 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Mar 09 14:33:05.391807 2019] [core:error] [pid 5157] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 9724
[Sat Mar 09 14:33:05.391818 2019] [core:notice] [pid 5157] AH00051: child pid 9726 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Mar 09 14:33:05.391821 2019] [core:error] [pid 5157] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 9726
[Sat Mar 09 14:33:05.391835 2019] [core:notice] [pid 5157] AH00051: child pid 9728 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Sat Mar 09 14:33:05.391837 2019] [core:error] [pid 5157] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 9728
```

**Software**

```
Ubuntu 18.10
Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu) 
Server built: 2018-10-03T13:57:22
PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.10.1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 14:54:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.10.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**Hardware**

```
/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         MS-7B46 (Default string)
/0                          bus            Z370 SLI PLUS (MS-7B46)
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3c                       memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/3c/0                     memory         [empty]
/0/3c/1                     memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/3c/2                     memory         [empty]
/0/3c/3                     memory         [empty]
/0/42                       memory         384KiB L1 cache
/0/43                       memory         1536KiB L2 cache
/0/44                       memory         9MiB L3 cache
/0/45                       processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8600K CPU @ 3.60GHz
/0/100                      bridge         8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/8                    generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
/0/100/14                   bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0      usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/9               bus            USB2.0 Hub
/0/100/14/0/9/2             input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/9/3             input          Wireless Receiver
/0/100/14/0/9/4             input          Wired Keyboard 600
/0/100/14/0/a               storage        USB FLASH DRIVE
/0/100/14/1      usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                 generic        200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/16                   communication  200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                   storage        200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/1c                   bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c.2                 bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0               display        GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
/0/100/1c.2/0.1             multimedia     GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c.4                 bridge         200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1c.4/0               bus            ASMedia Technology Inc.
/0/100/1c.4/0/0  usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.4/0/1  usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1f                   bridge         Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f.2                 memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                 multimedia     200 Series PCH HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                 bus            200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.6      enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
/0/1             scsi5      storage
/0/1/0.0.0       /dev/sda   disk           240GB DREVO X1 SSD
/0/1/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1  volume         498MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2  volume         99MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/3     /dev/sda3  volume         15MiB System partition
/0/1/0.0.0/4     /dev/sda4  volume         112GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/5     /dev/sda5  volume         43GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/6     /dev/sda6  volume         1258MiB Linux swap volume
/0/1/0.0.0/7     /dev/sda7  volume         24GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/8     /dev/sda8  volume         40GiB EXT4 volume
/0/2             scsi6      storage
/0/2/0.0.0       /dev/sdb   disk           31GB USB FLASH DRIVE
/0/2/0.0.0/0     /dev/sdb   disk           31GB
/0/2/0.0.0/0/1   /dev/sdb1  volume         28GiB Windows FAT volume
/1                          power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```

Comment: What is the hardware? This is either defective hardware (most likely) or a break-in attempt (unlikely).

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for your suggestion! I just added my hw configuration!